# Stencil.js - explanation of event listeners

Tags: javascript, events, stenciljs

Consider the following simple `input` component:

```js
import { Component, VNode, h, Prop, Host } from '@stencil/core'

@Component({
  tag: 'my-input',
})
export class MyInput {
  @Prop() inputId!: string
  @Prop() label!: string
  @Prop() value: string

  render(): VNode {
    return (
      <Host>
        <label htmlFor={this.inputId}>{this.label}</label>
        <input type="text" id={this.inputId} value={this.value}  />
      </Host>
    )
  }
}
```

Parent component that renders `<my-input>` component with couple of event listeners:

```js
import { Component, h, VNode } from '@stencil/core'

@Component({
  tag: 'my-page',
})
export class MyPage {
  private handleInput = (ev: Event) => {
    // this works
    console.log('handle input')
  }

  private handleFocus = (ev: Event) => {
    // this doesn't work
    console.log('handle focus')
  }

  private handleClick = (ev: Event) => {
    // this works
    console.log('handle click')
  }

  private handleBlur = (ev: Event) => {
    // this doesn't work
    console.log('handle blur')
  }

  render(): VNode {
    return (
      <my-input
        label="Label"
        inputId="testId"
        onInput={this.handleInput}
        onFocus={this.handleFocus}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        onBlur={this.handleBlur}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Would someone explain to me please, how it's possible that some of the listeners actually work and the rest do not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the focus and blur event handlers don't fire is because you're attaching the listeners to the `my-input` element and not the actual `input` element. That means only the listeners of events that bubble will fire (click, input) and the rest (focus, blur) won't.

One way to enable the use of those non-bubbling events is to proxy them:

```
export class MyInput {
  @Event() myFocus: EventEmitter<FocusEvent>;

  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        <label htmlFor={this.inputId}>{this.label}</label>
        <input type="text" id={this.inputId} value={this.value} onFocus={e => this.myFocus.emit(e)} />
      </Host>
    )
  }
}
```

Here I've attached an `focus` event handler to the `input` and fire the custom `myFocus` event which you can listen for from outside the component. You might also want to stop these events from bubbling by changing the decorator to `@Listen({ bubbles: false }) myFocus;`

This is also how the Ionic Framework (made by the same people as Stencil) does it, see https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/master/core/src/components/input/input.tsx#L220